# i18next Load translations from json files

Tags: javascript, jquery, translation, i18next

I have English json translation file in path: translation/en.json

I init i18next like this:

```
i18next.init({
    lng: navigator.language,
    fallbackLng : "en",
    backend: {
        loadPath: '/translation/{{lng}}.json',
    }
});
```

after running

```
i18next.t(KEY);
```

will print "KEY" and not its value in the translation file

it was working well when the translation were inside 'resource' parameter in i18next object. like below:

```
i18next.init({
    lng: navigator.language,
    fallbackLng : "en",
    resources: {
        en: {
            translation: {
                "KEY": "keyValue"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I use i18next framework

Comment: Can you confirm your .json file gets loaded if you look into the network tab of devtools? Also ```load: 'languageOnly'``` should be used if you only use the primary language.

Comment: json file isn't loaded. Also, I use more than one language.

Comment: Here's an example I use perhaps it will help you resolve your problem: https://pastebin.com/cbu0jCnZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used initImmediate:false which will wait translation to be loaded.

```
i18next
  .use(i18nextXHRBackend)
  .init({
    //debug:true,
    initImmediate: false, // set initImmediate false -> init method finished only when all resources/translation finish loading (async behaviour)
    lng: "en",
    fallbackLng : "en",
    backend:{
      loadPath: chrome.runtime.getURL('translation/{{lng}}.json')
    }
});
```

I used `chrome.runtime.getURL` since I use i18next in chrome extension and translation files should be loaded to this folder "translation"